# Количество Контроллеров и Моделей MVC

Tags: android

Если у меня есть 10 - 20 классов, значит мне надо создавать 10 - 20 Контроллеров и Моделей? Или есть другие способы сократить количество Контроллеров и Моделей?

Comment: В андроиде паттерн MVC [уже реализован системой](http://www.appstoremarketresearch.com/articles/android-tutorial-model-view-controller-architecture/) - model - данные, view - разметка, controller - активити.

Answer (score 1):

Каких классов? В Андроиде в качестве контроллера выступает обычно активити или фрагмент. А модель по сути это то откуда берутся данные и например база данных или с интернета. Принято  для таких вариантов создавать одну модель на все приложение